# Navigation game that chooses a random number to either show victory or defeat

Tags: java

I have to do a problem with navigation flow, where I press a button and it randomly chooses B or defeat. if B in chosen then move on to C. C chooses either victory or defeat. The function being in one managed bean. I've got the html done for the most part, but I can't get my function to work.

This is my bean.

```
public class Navigation

 public String randomGame(String s){
    String result;
    double x = Math.random();
    if (s.equals("a")){
        if (x > 0.5)
            result = "Defeat?faces-redirect=true";
        else
            result = "B?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else if (s.equals("b")){
        if (x < 0.5)
            result = "Defeat2?faces-redirect=true";
        else
            result = "C?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else
    {
        if (x < 0.5)
            result = "Defeat?faces-redirect=true";
        else
            result = "Victory?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

This is the index for the starting page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>MP1 Game</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p>Click "START" to play!</p>
    <h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Start" action="#{navigation.randomGame('a')}" />
    <input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="self.close()"></input>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

I can't get my function to work correct, it only cycles through B and Defeated, could some one give me some tips

Comment: I believe this question would be more suitable at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you changed the character in your xHtml page from 'a' to 'b' and 'c', right here: action="#{navigation.randomGame('a')}"

Answer (score 0):

consider 
x = 0.4;
s = 'a'

the first else condition will redirect you to page B however, x is still less than 0.5.

```
if (x < 0.5)
            result = "Defeat2?faces-redirect=true";
```

becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

@WhiteShadowDaCoder The solution to that would be:

```
public String randomGame(String s){
    String result;
    double x = Math.random();
    if (s.equals("a")){
        if (x > 0.5)
            return "Defeat?faces-redirect=true";
        else
            return "B?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else if (s.equals("b")){
        if (x < 0.5)
            return "Defeat2?faces-redirect=true";
        else
           ...
```

return the result will jump to the end of the function, while setting the variable will still check the other conditions (that don't need to be checked).